# Using algebraic geometry to calculate the ring of integers of a number field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

In section 13 chapter 1 of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory,* he shows how rings of integers can be seen as one dimensional curves, with the integral closure of a ring corresponding to the normalization of the original curve. In this case, we can check if a ring is integrally closed by checking if it is nonsingular at each point. However, this is where my knowledge of algebraic geometry ends. I know when you have a variety $V$ over a field $k$ a point $p$ is nonsingular if and only if $Dim_k$ $\frak{m}/\frak{m^2}$ $=$ $Dim V.$ However, I don't know how one would translate this to the case for general schemes, or if this is practical at all. Is there anything related to what I'm saying?

Edit: I've thought about it a bit, and I think the way to formalize this is that a one dimensional ring is integrally closed iff all its localizations to primes are principal rings. However, like a hydra, I now have three new questions:

1. How do you prove this?
2. What does it mean in the full ring if one of its localizations are not principal?
   And
3. How practical is this reformulation? Though for a fixed, specific prime this condition seems very difficult to prove for some prime one doesn't explicitly have, let alone the infinitely many primes that are in the integers.

Comment: there's a great book called an invitation to arithmetic geometry which likely answers most of your questions

Comment: @littleman - If $A$ is a noetherian local domain of dimension 1 it follows $A$ is a DVR iff $A$ is regular in the sense that $dim_k(m/m^2)=1$. From this it follows that a noetherian integral domain $A$ of dimension $1$ is integrally closed iff it is regular. See Atiyah-Macdonald Theorem 9.3

Comment: Im unsure what you mean when you want to "use algebraic geometry to calculate the ring of integers in a number field" - what does this mean? Some general properties are known for such "rings of integers" (which you find in the book of Neukirch): For any number field $K$ it follows the ring of integers $A=\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank.